# Mixin common fields between serializers in Django Rest Framework

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, mixins

I have this:

```
class GenericCharacterFieldMixin():
    attributes = serializers.SerializerMethodField('character_attribute')
    skills = serializers.SerializerMethodField('character_skill')

    def character_attribute(self, obj):
        character_attribute_fields = {}
        character_attribute_fields['mental'] = {str(trait_item.get()): trait_item.get().current_value
                                                for trait_item in obj.mental_attributes}
        character_attribute_fields['physical'] = {str(trait_item.get()): trait_item.get().current_value
                                                  for trait_item in obj.physical_attributes}
        character_attribute_fields['social'] = {str(trait_item.get()): trait_item.get().current_value
                                                for trait_item in obj.social_attributes}
        return character_attribute_fields

    def character_skill(self, obj):
        character_skill_fields = {}
        character_skill_fields['mental'] = {str(trait_item.get()): trait_item.get().current_value
                                            for trait_item in obj.mental_skills}
        character_skill_fields['physical'] = {str(trait_item.get()): trait_item.get().current_value
                                              for trait_item in obj.physical_skills}
        character_skill_fields['social'] = {str(trait_item.get()): trait_item.get().current_value
                                            for trait_item in obj.social_skills}
        return character_skill_fields


class MageSerializer(GenericCharacterFieldMixin, serializers.ModelSerializer):
    player = serializers.ReadOnlyField(source='player.username')
    arcana = serializers.SerializerMethodField()

    def get_arcana(self, obj):
        if obj:
            return {str(arcana): arcana.current_value for arcana in obj.linked_arcana.all()}

    class Meta:
        model = Mage
        fields = ('id', 'player', 'name', 'sub_race', 'faction', 'is_published',
                  'power_level', 'energy_trait', 'virtue', 'vice', 'morality', 'size',
                  'arcana', 'attributes', 'skills')
        depth = 1
```

`GenericCharacterFieldMixin` is a Mixin of Fields for Characters, that are Generic, i.e. common to all types of characters.

I'd like my Mage Serializer to have these 'mixed in' rather than c/p then between all types of character (Mage is a type of character) hopefully this will increase DRYness in my webapp.

The issue is on the model I have this:

```
class NWODCharacter(models.Model):

    class Meta:
        abstract = True
        ordering = ['updated_date', 'created_date']

    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    player = models.ForeignKey('auth.User', related_name="%(class)s_by_user")
    ....

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        ...

    attributes = GenericRelation('CharacterAttributeLink')
    skills = GenericRelation('CharacterSkillLink')
```

Which means I get this error:

```
TypeError at /characters/api/mages
<django.contrib.contenttypes.fields.create_generic_related_manager.<locals>.GenericRelatedObjectManager object at 0x00000000051CBD30> is not JSON serializable
```

**Django Rest Framework thinks I want to serialize my generic relationship.**

If I rename the fields in the model (`s/attributes/foos/g`, `s/skills/bars/g`) then I get a different (less clear?) error :

```
ImproperlyConfigured at /characters/api/mages
Field name `attributes` is not valid for model `ModelBase`.
```

How do I pull those methods and fields into a mixin, without confusing DRF?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Solution is simple as changing

```
class GenericCharacterFieldMixin():
```

to

```
class GenericCharacterFieldMixin(serializers.Serializer):
```

Comment: Is this something new?

Comment: @Pureferret, it's short answer to question. I met same issue today, and found this solution cleaner than user1376455 answer.

Answer (score 37):

Set `SerializerMetaclass`:

```py
from rest_framework import serializers

class GenericCharacterFieldMixin(metaclass=serializers.SerializerMetaclass):
    # ...
```

This is the solution [recommended by DRF's authors](https://github.com/encode/django-rest-framework/issues/4482).

Solutions suggested in the previous answers are problematic:

1. user1376455's solution hacks DRF into registering the mixin's fields in `_declared_fields` by declaring them on the child as different fields. This hack might not work in subsequent versions of the framework.
2. Nikolay Fominyh's solution changes the mixin to a fully fledged serializer (note that due to this, the name `GenericCharacterFieldMixin` is very unfortunate for a class which is not a mixin, but a serializer!). This is problematic because it takes the full `Serializer` class into the multiple inheritance, see the [DRF issue](https://github.com/encode/django-rest-framework/issues/4482) for examples demonstrating why this is a bad idea.

Answer (score 3):

i had same issue and my google search brought me here. i managed to solve it.
 since you are including attributes and skill fields in serialiser, you need to provide serialisation method for it.

this worked for me

```
class MageSerializer(GenericCharacterFieldMixin, serializers.ModelSerializer):
    player = serializers.ReadOnlyField(source='player.username')
    arcana = serializers.SerializerMethodField()


    attributes = serializers.PrimaryKeyRelatedField(many=True, 
                                read_only= True)
    skills = serializers.PrimaryKeyRelatedField(many=True, 
                                read_only= True)


    def get_arcana(self, obj):
      if obj:
        return {str(arcana): arcana.current_value for arcana in obj.linked_arcana.all()}

    class Meta:
        model = Mage
        fields = ('id', 'player', 'name', 'sub_race', 'faction', 'is_published',
                  'power_level', 'energy_trait', 'virtue', 'vice', 'morality', 'size',
                  'arcana', 'attributes', 'skills')
        depth = 1
```