# How can I use non-model serializer mixins with a ModelSerializer

Tags: django-rest-framework

Say I have a mixin like `CaptchaSerializerMixin` that has a field `captcha` that I don't have on the model. Currently I need to do:

```
class MyModel(CaptchaSerializerMixin, serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = MyModel
        fields = ['id', 'captcha']
```

Or it won't accept the `captcha` field. How can my Mixin supply itself to the fields list?

Answer (score 1):

You need to make sure `CaptchaSerializerMixin` inherit from `Serializer`. If you don't do that, fields won't be identified as `serializers.Field`.

Answer (score 0):

When writing a mixin that applies on a `ModelSerializer` (Linovia’s approach should work on plain serializers), you need to use the `SerializerMetaClass` like this:

```py
class CaptchaSerializerMixin(metaclass=serializers.SerializerMetaClass):
    captcha = SomeField()
```

You do still need to mention "captcha" in your `Meta.fields`.

Similar more detailed answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/58304791/2547556

The above is the recommended way, but if you really can’t mention it in your `Meta.fields`, then a hacky way would be:

```py
class MyModel(CaptchaSerializerMixin, serializers.ModelSerializer):
    def get_fields(self):
        fields = super().get_fields()
        fields.update(CaptchaSerializerMixin.get_fields(self))
        return fields

    class Meta:
        model = MyModel
        fields = ['id']
```